# How to add a word after a particular line in a text?

Tags: python

I am trying to add a word after a particular line in my file. I am using infile and a reference and trying to create outfile. The infile and reference are the same type, but the reference contains the TER word at a particular position. I want to add the TER word into the outfile (basically create a copy of infile and add the TER from the reference). 
I am trying to search by a number (resnum in the code) but there will be a problem as many consecutive lines have the same number. 
Can anybody help?

```
from sys import argv
import argparse

script,infile,outfile, reference = argv
Ter = []
res = []


def get_Ter(reference):
    reference_1 = open(reference,"r")
    for line in reference_1:
        contents = line.split(" ")
        if contents[0] == "TER":
        resnum = line[22:27]
        resname = line[17:20]
        chain = line[21]
        Ter.append(resnum)

        def find_TER(infile,outfile):
            with open(infile, "r") as infile_1:
                content = infile_1.readlines()
            with open(outfile, "w+") as outfile_1:
                outfile_1.write(content)
                if line[0:6] == "ATOM  ":
                    resnum_1 = line[22:27]
                    res.append(resnum_1)
                    if resnum_1 in res == resnum in Ter:
                        outfile_1.write(line + "\nTER")

        find_TER(infile,outfile)
get_Ter(reference)
```

example of a file (this is the reference, the infile is the same but missing the TER). They are all nicely lined up underneath each other (The formatting here):
ATOM    992  SG  CYX D 452      23.296  45.745  28.572  1.00  0.00
ATOM    993  C   CYX D 452      20.742  42.431  27.841  1.00  0.00
ATOM    994  O   CYX D 452      20.689  41.447  28.565  1.00  0.00
ATOM    995  OXT CYX D 452      19.788  42.822  27.185  1.00  0.00
TER     995      CYS D 452
ATOM    996  N   ARG D 492      27.510  26.357  34.041  1.00  0.00
ATOM    997  H1  ARG D 492      26.590  26.591  33.694  1.00  0.00
ATOM    998  H2  ARG D 492      28.138  27.135  34.182  1.00  0.00
ATOM    999  H3  ARG D 492      27.422  26.030  34.993  1.00  0.00
ATOM   1000  CA  ARG D 492      28.179  25.410  33.192  1.00  0.00

Now I have this:

```
from sys import argv
import argparse

   script,infile,outfile, reference = argv
   Ter = []
   res = []

def get_Ter(reference):
    reference_1 = open(reference,"r")
    for line in reference_1:
        contents = line.split(" ")
    if contents[0] == "TER":
        ternum = line[22:27]

        def find_TER(infile,outfile):
            with open(infile, "r") as infile_1:
                content = infile_1.readlines()
            with open(outfile, "w+") as outfile_1:
                for line in content:
                    outfile_1.write(line)
                    line = line.split(" ")
                    if line[0] == "ATOM":
                        resnum = line[22:27]
                        if ternum == resnum:




                            find_TER(infile,outfile)
get_Ter(reference)
```

Comment: No. I did try a different code (related) and asked before the weekend. Its a common format in bioinformatics.

Comment: The repair doesn't work because the you haven't put in the rest of the logic, and you've put it in the wrong place. Also, your file-handling logic is incorrect; you should open the files *once* at the start of the program, not every time you hit a TER reference.

Comment: For the overall problems, you really need to sit down with someone beside you and get a little tutoring help in program flow; that's beyond the realm of Stack Overflow.  Rewriting this for you is also too involved a response for here.

Comment: I do recommend one tactic until you can grab someone: try incremental programming.  Write just a few lines of code and make sure they work before you go on to the next.  For instance. start by opening **infile** and writing it to **outfile**, one line at a time.  Then add code that interprets the input line (breaks it into the needed fields).  Third, open the reference file and read it, keeping it in synch with **infile**.  Next, identify TER lines and find matching lines in **infile** -- just print a message when you find one.  See how that works, bit by bit?

Comment: Thank you, I will try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic logic is twofold:

1. Determine when you need the TER line and generate it.  (You've done this.)
2. Detect when it's time to write that line to the output.

All you really need to do for the second part is to recognize that you have a pending TER output for resnum 452 (or whatever number it is).  You can do this with a simple variable: keep it at -1 until you have a valid resnum.

As you read, you check that resnum consistently.  If it's positive and different from the most recent input line, then you have to print the TER line before doing anything else.  Something like this:

```
contents = line.split():
resnum = line[22:27]
if ternum > 0 and ternum != int(resnum):
    # write out the TER line
    ternum = -1

# continue with rest of the program.
if contents[0] == "TER":
    ...
```

You might also need to check at end of file, in case the last resnum has a hanging TER line to print out.

Is that enough to move you along?

Comment: Sorry, I have on this for a while and my brain is fried. Where do I put this?

Comment: I am only just beginning to code so I dont really get what you are saying.

Comment: My apology as well; I had this within the TER processing.  As the new version show, this goes just after you split the input line into **contents**.

Comment: Thanks, but still a bit too hard for me. Its just confusing:( Where does ternum comes from?

Comment: **ternum** is the resnum associated with the TER line, just as you added.  Now save the TER line in a variable, and then insert the code from my answer.

Comment: You can see I am clearly struggling. I have no idea what you mean, save it in a variable (it is in variable), check the end line etc. I appreciate your help but these bits and bobs wont get me anywhere. I have written if ternum == down the bottom but it doesnt work:(